# Can we use Spock with plain Java

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I started on working with Spock from couple of days and in all the documentations I have seen the tests are written in Groovy. Is there any way to use Spock in plain Java class? Because we have a requirement to use only Java as programming language.

Comment: "Because we have a requirement to use only Java as programming language." - If the requirement is really to only use Java then no, you cannot use Spock.  If the requirement is to only use Java in your application code and that restriction may not apply to your unit tests (which it shouldn't) then yes, you can use Spock.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spock makes extensive use of Groovy magic such as AST transforms, and you can only write Spock tests in Groovy. However, you can certainly use Spock to test Java-only code and not include Groovy or any Groovy-based code in your compile scope.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using spock and groovy only for tests and must say it's awesome mix!

Check this project used for workshop during codepot.pl conference:

https://github.com/codepot-groovy-android/groovy_no_way_back

The app and tests both use groovy, with tests using spock as well.

But there is also a branch with with app written in Java and only tests in groovy with spock:

https://github.com/codepot-groovy-android/groovy_no_way_back/tree/codepot/livetesting

Answer (score 1):

As others said if the requirement is for production code to be Java, yes you can use Spock to test Java code. In fact I wrote a book on this subject alone :-)

https://www.manning.com/books/java-testing-with-spock

If the requirement is that all code should be in java (including unit tests) then no, Spock cannot be used.